# Inclusion in a proof (cts image of a compact metrizable space is metrizable)

Tags: general-topology

May I refer you to:
[image]

taken from [page 92 of *Infinite Dimensional Analysis* by Charalambos D. Aliprantis.](http://books.google.com.mx/books?id=4hIq6ExH7NoC&pg=PA92&lpg=PA92&dq=continuous+image+of+a+compact+metrizable+space+is+metrizable&source=bl&ots=p8uRTpf1LC&sig=9JV01MhywqlHkHaEjpBtzaoELbk&hl=es&ei=9ZciTfz_F4fWtQOmv_yICw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBA#v=onepageq=continuous%20image%20of%20a%20compact%20metrizable%20space%20is%20metrizable&f=false)

Why $G \subset f^{-1}(W)$ ? I don't see this inclusion. Can you please help?

Comment: Not everyone will have access to the page (I get a message saying I have no access or have used up my access for this book); is it really that much work for you to summarize the point in addition to providing a *discreet* link to the page for the benefit of those who can?

Comment: You will need to take appropriate basis elements to guarantee that $G \subseteq f^{-1}(W)$. Since $W$ is open in $Y$ and $y \in W$, $f^{-1}(W)$ is open in $X$ and contains $f^{-1}(y)$. For each $x \in f^{-1}(y)$, let $B_x \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B_x \subseteq f^{-1}(W)$. The collection $ C = \{B_x : x \in f^{-1}(y)\}$ is an open cover of $f^{-1}(y)$. Now use the fact that $f^{-1}(y)$ is compact to obtain a finite subcover of $C$ containing $f^{-1}(y)$ and let $G$ be their union. Thus $f^{-1}(y) \subseteq G \subseteq f^{-1}(W)$.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of Corollary 3.43: http://i.imgur.com/ZKZaI.jpg

Comment: @Nuno: Thanks: I've uploaded the image into the question in the place of the ugly long link.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: Thank you too for adding it to the question. It's much better now.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative proof: Of course $Y = f[X]$ is compact and Hausdorff. It has a countable network (which is like a base of a space but without the requirement that its members are open sets), as a continuous image of a space with a countable network. A compact Hausdorff space with a countable network is second-countable (Arhangel'skij's theorem) and we are done by Urysohn. For a proof of the stuff on networks, I have a post [here](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2005;task=show_msg;msg=1755) that explains it (at the end it goes into networks).